# Python-Audio edit audio as it plays

Tags: python, audio, asynchronous, python-2.6

i am looking for a Python library that allows to read an audio file, edit it on the fly and output it as it's read. What I want to create is a simple DJs software for my friend, so I really need a library thats allow to live-edit audio files and output it to the speakers.

I've taked a look to Nsound, and I loved it, but I have'nt understand how to live-stream the output.

PyMedia seemed a good choice as it's asynchronimous, but it seems that it does'nt allows me to apply effects to the sound.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion,
Matt.

Comment: What kind of editing do you want to support?  Mixing with other tracks?  EQ?  Other effects?

Comment: Exactly, working with EQ, overload track parts, loop a small part of the MP3s for a while, and other things like that. ^^

Comment: Your "simple DJ software" isn't so simple.  I think you're going to end up writing most of this from scratch.  Start by looking for a library that simply outputs a buffer of data.  The input doesn't matter at this point.

Comment: PyMedia can handle the buffer output by taking wav files, so there are no problems. It works fine, but i can't edit the audio. https://gist.github.com/2046205

Comment: Sure you can.  Just modify the data in the buffer.  Of course how you do that is quite complicated.  You're going to want to post a new question for each type of DSP effect you want.

Comment: I've just released nsound-0.9.1, which includes real-time playback.  Check out the examples bebot.py and piano.py.